# Split oracle sorted procedure into their own separate objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle

I need to separate a file called procedures.sql where I have this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE nameOfPackage AS
    procedure name1
        (
           column  data type
        )
    procedure name2
        (
           column  data type
        )
       ....
```

I want to separate this into their own objects and create a table with each version of this procedures, what is the best way to separate them?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You also included the python tags. What does python have to do with Oracle packages?

Comment: I'm not sure that what you want is what you should do. Packages are here for reason. They let you "store" procedures, functions, types, ... that "work" with the same problem at one place. If you move procedures, functions, ... out of the package, you'll also have to modify all code that references them because package will no longer exist. Besides, you'll lose that nice functionality of having them all at the same place. From my point of view, it is one of the **version control systems** you need, such as Git, Subversion, ...

Comment: I will create a lookup table  including each version of the procedures